# Where to download SAP SDK for ASE (Windows Server 2019)?

Tags: sybase, sybase-ase-15.7

Where do we download SAP SAP SDK for ASE (Windows Server 2019)?  Trying to connect to Sybase DB server using SQLDBX on Windows Server 2019 client and it cant find required dll (libsybct.dll).  I I assume that I need to download SAP SDK for ASE but not sure where to download.  Anyone know where to download?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea what `SQLDBX` requires re: connecting to `ASE` so fwiw ...

If you absolutely positively need the (older) `ASE 15.7 SDK` download, and you have an active SAP support contract, your best bet would be to obtain the `SDK` through your account's download capability @ support.sap.com.

Otherwise you can find downloads of the last few releases of the `ASE 16.0 SDK` @ [SAP: Free Trials and Downloads](https://developers.sap.com/trials-downloads.html).  Generally speaking these should be backwards compatible with `ASE 15.7`.